# How do I get reference to DOM element in jQuery based on DOM element's contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>    
  </tr>  
</table>
```

How can I get reference to `<td>2</td>`? 
I need reference as I want to trigger event on it.

Comment: You can loop the childs and check the value.

Comment: @Hardy It won't work because 2 might not be at the same position in my specific problem

Comment: Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1520429/5277216

Answer (score 1):

Just loop like:

```js
$('table td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === '2') {
    // trigger some event
    $(this).doTheThing();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td:contains("2")')
```

Selects the td with number 2 inside.

Answer (score 1):

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

*Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.*

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "2";
}).trigger("whatever");
```